# setting fuelux datagrid column cellls to string from object collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, fuelux

MY fuelux datagrid look like this inside backbone render function

```
    var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
            columns: [
                                     {
                                           property: 'id',
                                           label: 'id',
                                          sortable: true
                                     },
                {
                    property: 'name',
                    label: 'groups',
                    sortable: true
                },
                {
                    property: 'name',
                    label: 'Roles',
                    sortable: true
                }
            ],
            data: this.collection,
            delay: 250
        });
        $('#sectionName').html('Groups');
        $('#MyGrid').datagrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            stretchHeight: true
        });
```

this.collection return json as follows

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "roles":[
                {"id":1,"authority":"ROLE1"},
                {"id":2,"authority":"ROLE2"},
                {"id":3,"authority":"ROLE3"}
            ],
    "groups":[
                {"id":1,"name":"A"},
                {"id":2,"name":"B"},
                {"id":3,"name":"C"}
          ]
},
{
    "id":2,
    "roles":[
                {"id":5,"authority":"ROLE4"},
                {"id":5,"authority":"ROLE5"},
                {"id":6,"authority":"ROLE6"}
            ],
    "groups":[
                {"id":4,"name":"D"},
                {"id":5,"name":"E"},
                {"id":6,"name":"F"}
          ]
}
```

]

I want fuelux datagrid to have column  id, roles and groups. it should look like as below:

```
    id        roles                        groups
    1         role1, role2 , role3          A, B, C
    12        role3, role4 , role5          D, E, F
```

I tried to write formatter function something like this but it did not work

```
 var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
        columns: [
            {
                property: 'id',
                label: 'id',
                sortable: true
            },
            {
                property: 'name',
                label: 'groups',
                sortable: true
            },
            {
                property: 'name',
                label: 'Roles',
                sortable: true
            }
        ], 

       formatter: function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                                    item.roles= //string made from groups with comma
                    item.groups= //string made from roles with comma

            },
        data: this.collection,
        delay: 250
    });

    $('#MyGrid').datagrid({
       //as above
    });
  formatter: function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                   item.roles= //string of roles made from roles with comma
                                   item.groups= /string of groups made from groups with comma 
                });
            },
```

It would be great help if somebody here can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

for your column defs each `property` should match the property names returned by your datasource.  Try this:

```
{
    property: 'id',
    label: 'ID',
    sortable: true
},
{
    property: 'roles',
    label: 'Roles',
    sortable: true
},
{
    property: 'groups',
    label: 'Groups',
    sortable: true
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually, that displays [object object]. I want to display infact role cell for first model as role1, role2 , role3 and as role4, role5 , role 6 for second model inside the cell. I tried even roles[0].name for test and even that dosent get displayed.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with your use case to provide specifics, but as long as the property contains a string (with text and/or html) by the time it reaches the datagrid it will be displayed as you expect.  The job of your datasource and formatter function is to convert the data into the format expected by the datagrid.

Comment: thanks for your hints on line "The job of your datasource and formatter function is to convert the data into the format expected by the datagrid.". Presently, I solved my problem. But, the datagird broke it sorting, searching, etc. Should i set them inside datasource?

Comment: Yes, on all paging and sorting the datagrid will call your datasource's `data` function again and pass the options that were selected.  You then return the data the grid is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve my problem as follows

```
 formatter: function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    var roleCell = new app.RoleSupplier({ model: item      });
                    roleCell.render();
                    item.roles = roleCell.$el; //set property name above to roles
                });
            },
```

Then, I created RoleSupplier as below

```
 app.RolesSupplier = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#roles-cell-template').html()),
    render: function (eventName) {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

I created template as below

```
 <script type="text/template" id="roles-cell-template">
        <div>
            <@ _.each(roles.toJSON(), function( role, index, list ){ @>
                <@ if(index < (list.length - 1)) { @>
                    <@=role.authority + ','@>
                <@ } else { @>
                    <@=role.authority@>
                <@ } @>
            <@ }); @>

        </div>  
    </script>
```

This worked for me. But, what user of fuelux have to understand is:

- you can set property name to name of key in json to set their value

  > > property:'id',
  > >       label:'ID' //will set id value to column name ID
- If you have some json value and you like to display them in specific way, or you cant some html in cell, you format them as below

  > > ```
  > > formatter: function (items) {
  > >                 $.each(items, function (index, item) {
  > >                      item.yourPropertyName1= format your html here that you want  appear in label1
  > >                      item.yourProeprtyName 2= fromat your html like button , anything you want inside column cell of label2                 
  > >                 });
  > >             },
  > > ```